# LIKE ILIKE SQL operators doesn't work correclty

Tags: php, mysql, suitecrm

I have database with phone numbers.

Like this number 00987456321 I want to be able to search on the number by typing the whole number or part of it for example 321 or 4563 or 7456321

From what I know I need "Like" or "Ilike" operators

I tried both but it gave me all numbers in the database.

I tried with "=" and it gives me the phone number but only if I write it completely so my code is working but the operators doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$searchFields['Leads'] = array (
  'phone' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'default',
    'operator' => 'ILIKE',
    'db_field' => 
    array (
      0 => 'phone_mobile',
      1 => 'phone_work',
      2 => 'phone_other',
      3 => 'phone_fax',
      4 => 'phone_home',
    ),
  ),
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a framework or some DB library? It's hard to tell what you might be doing wrong if we don't know what you're using.

Comment: @El_Vanja I'm using SuiteCRM system/SugerCRM, It looks so weird for me too

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this CRM and am finding it difficult to find documentation about defining SQL queries.

Comment: @El_Vanja here is the page https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/metadata/#_searchdefs_php

Comment: I'm not finding any mention of operators in there.

Comment: @El_Vanja This is the best page that I found, It's not about operators, It's about the search function in SuiteCRM https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/administration-panel/search/elasticsearch/syntax/

Comment: I've seen that one. Doesn't mention anything about SQL queries. That concerns Elasticsearch.

Comment: You showed us some array, which is probably passed as a configuration for some function/method, but didn't show us how do you use it later, so it's hard to guess what are you doing with it. Check your CRMs docs if it is possible to debug SQL, optionaly go deeper into the code and debug it yourself i.e. with Xdebug, to find what exactly SQL (if any) is generated and why its wrong.

Comment: Back to your other question which you deleted (no country prefix search) searching specific phone number by its last 4 or 6 digits is absolutely pointless, as it can give you from several to thousands of results and as I understood you need (in that case) just one.

Comment: @biesior after reading the CRM code It turns out that the system came with wildcard option, If A user type %966 it will show all numbers that have this number, and That's what exactly what I was trying to do. I didn't solve it but at least I discovered a useful future that no body know in our company lol :P